# Trac - How do I access Custom Ticket Fields in ITicketChangeListener?

Tags: python, plugins, trac

I'm trying to write my own [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) [plugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment) to notify an external system of changes to tickets matching a certain criteria.  From my research so far, I've figured out that implementing the [ITicketChangeListener interface](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-0.11.7/trac/ticket/api.py#L113) is the way to go.

The method definitions are all very straight forward, but what's not straight forward for me is the [Ticket object](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-0.11.7/trac/ticket/model.py) and accessing its custom fields.  I've learned that you can access default ticket fields as simply as:

```
# t is a Ticket object
theStatus = t['status']
```

I've found several sources that say this won't work:

```
myCustomField = t['my_custom_field']
```

Yet none of them tell me what *will* work.

In addition, I need to know if the `old_values` argument of the `ticket_changed()` method will have my custom fields or if I'll have to do something different there as well.

I'm fairly new to Python and *very* new to Trac. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources are wrong about [custom ticket fields](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTicketsCustomFields). The value-by-name approach should work. And *old_values* contains all fields values, including custom fields too. That's it.

You may want to look at the [TracAnnouncer](http://trac-hacks.org/browser/announcerplugin/trunk/announcer/producers.py?rev=9142) source for some change-listener coding examples.

Comment: Right you are.  That did work.  However, I still had problems with the key not existing sometimes in `old_values`. So I had to check first with: if "my_custom_field" in old_values:

Comment: Right, the key will only exist in `old_values` if the value of the ticket field has changed.